# Интересует мнение о создании формы отправки писем на Hanami

Tags: ruby, form, sendmail

Если Вы опробовали работоспособность формы в своём проекте, созданном на [Hanami](http://hanamirb.org/guides/1.0/helpers/forms/), то могли бы вы описать плюсы и минусы данного выбора?

До этого использовал форму, созданную на php, но не очень доволен результатами её работы, хочется найти решение: стабильное и без лагов.

Comment: От нестабильности и лагов надо избавляться не путём смены технологии, а путём выяснения, где возникают и чем вызваны задержки и падения. И только если из этого возникнет вывод о том, что есть технология, позволяющая это же без изменений сделать лучше -- только тогда рассматривать переход. PS: на StackOverflow не любят сбор мнений, этот вопрос будет закрыт.